# starting a route with a parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I would like to create a  route like this:

```
Route::get('{env?}/apps', array('as' => 'apps', 'uses' => 'AppController@apps'));
```

I cant seem to get this to work when the parameter is not there, I have made it optional and also created my controller to take the optional parameter. Is there a way to do this?

Controller:

```
    public function apps($env = null )
    {
            $apps = Apps::AppList($env)->get();
            $apps=$apps->toJson();
            print_r($apps);

    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to start with an `env` anyway? Why not swap them around?

Comment: This is just a guess, but I think that the non-optional parameters must come first. Maybe someone could check the [source](http://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/master/src/Illuminate/Routing) for an evidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by using more of a workaround.

```
Route::get('{env?}/apps', array('as' => 'apps', 'uses' => 'AppController@apps'));
Route::get('apps', array('as' => 'appsall', 'uses' => 'AppController@apps'));
```

the second route will allow just "/apps" to work

Answer (score 0):

just try

`Route::get('{env}/apps', array('as' => 'apps', 'uses' => 'AppController@apps'));`

Comment: this is what I am doing except I want the parameter to be optional...thats why I have the "?". your answer simply make the parameter not optional.....